# Need help creating a QPX Express request with Google APIs Client Library for PHP

Tags: php, json, api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to do find the lowest prices for special flights and would like to use the [QPX Express API](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/) provided by Google Developers. Since I am a PHP developer, I thought the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#google-apis-client-library-for-php) is the method of choice for me.

However, I get stuck when it comes to combinig the PHP API with the QPX Express API:

Concerning QPX Express, I know I have to create a JSON object that has to be sent to the API, which can even easily be done by the Demo on https://qpx-express-demo.itasoftware.com/ .

Concerning the PHP API Client, I think I have to create a Client object and the QPX Express Service object, like so:

```
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/QPXExpress.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Testing");
$client->setDeveloperKey("MY_APP_KEY");
$service = new Google_Service_QPXExpress($client);
```

(I have already created a new project and an API KEY in the Google Developers Console.)

But then I do not know what to with it in order to send the JSON request and receive a JSON Response. I either did not find the correct resource, or I am lacking knowledge about RESTful APIs... Unfortunately, I did not find something like a tutorial for that special case (PHP API and QPX), and the [simple example](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/QPXExpress.php) did not help much, neither did the QPX Express reference. So, I hope someone can put me on the right track... Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
With the help of the first answer by [ämbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587895/need-help-creating-a-qpx-express-request-with-google-apis-client-library-for-php/24588033#24588033), I came up with the following code, which results in a Fatal Error.

The code:

```
require_once 'Client.php';
require_once 'Service/QPXExpress.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Testing");
$client->setDeveloperKey("[myKey]");
$service = new Google_Service_QPXExpress($client);
$request = new Google_Service_QPXExpress_TripOptionsRequest();
$request->setMaxPrice('EUR200');
$searchRequest = new Google_Service_QPXExpress_TripsSearchRequest();
$searchRequest->setRequest($request);
$result = $service->trips->search($searchRequest);
```

The resulting error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=[myKey]: (500) Backend Error' in C:\dev\www\Google\Http\REST.php:79
Stack trace:
#0 C:\dev\www\Google\Http\REST.php(44): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#1 C:\dev\www\Google\Client.php(499): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 C:\dev\www\Google\Service\Resource.php(195): Google_Client-&gt;execute(Object(Google_Http_Request))
#3 C:\dev\www\Google\Service\QPXExpress.php(91): Google_Service_Resource-&gt;call('search', Array, 'Google_Service_...')
#4 C:\dev\www\fluege.php(13): Google_Service_QPXExpress_Trips_Resource-&gt;search(Object(Google_Service_QPXExpress_TripsSearchRequest))
#5 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\dev\www\Google\Http\REST.php</b> on line <b>79</b>
```

Does the mistake catch anyone's eye?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm in the same boat.  I'm a web dev mostly working in PHP as of late, and I'm trying to integrate the QPX Express API into a project. I started out the same way you did, but had no success.  I'm not entirely sure QPX works with the API library for PHP,  so I started over, and came up with this using curl, which is what the API recommends:

```
<?php
$data = array ( "request" => array(
            "passengers" => array( 
                    adultCount => 1
                        ),
                    "slice" => array( 
                            array(
                                origin => "BOS",
                                destination => "LAX",
                                date => "2014-09-09"),
                            array(
                                origin => "LAX",
                                destination => "BOS",
                                date => "2014-09-10"),
                            ),
                                solutions => "1"
                            ),                   
             );                                                                                   
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=MyAPIKey');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

/* then I echo the result for testing purposes */

echo $result;

?>
```

This is where I am right now.  Of course, the search variables can be set up with PHP, and the   `solutions => "1"` can be set to the number of solutions you need. Hope it helps!

Comment: This looks pretty well, thank you very much for sharing that! Since this question is not opened frequently, I also already thought about using cURL instead of the PHP API. I have copied your code and run it, but I only get a `bool(false)` result. I assume that my API key was not created correctly, or cURL does not work properly on my local machine... EDIT: the code works like a charm on the live server. :-)

Comment: Glad I could help.  It took me a while to figure it out.  I'm going to edit the code a little to limit the results to 'x' number of solutions.  If you plan to use this code, please select 'accept' this answer.  I'm new to this forum, so my reputation needs all the help it can get!

Comment: Beside the `"solutions"` definition, I also defined the "maxPrice" parameter, and I defined the fields that I want in my response. The response fields can be added to the URL directly. In my case, I wanted to have the flight data and the price: `https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=MY_API_KEY&fields=trips(tripOption(saleTotal,slice(segment(leg(arrivalTime,departureTime,origin,destination,originTerminal,duration,operatingDisclosure)))))` (Learned about the fields on https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/how-tos/performance#partial-response)

Comment: @travallia_jeff, Thanks man you made my day. This is a great solution. I will play around it and discover it in depth.

Comment: I have the same problem but this code not working for me... I get this error: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest", "message": "Invalid inputs for request id \"myid\": Input error for \"tripOptions\" (search), \"x.slices[*].origin\" is required." } ], "code": 400, "message": "Invalid inputs for request id \"myid\": Input error for \"tripOptions\" (search), \"x.slices[*].origin\" is required." } }  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to make the Google APIs Client Library for PHP work. Main problem is that documentation is not clear enough on which params are required for the search. After reading [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/faq) section and the simplest JSON request in [DEMO](https://qpx-express-demo.itasoftware.com/), found out that:

```
{
  "request": {
    "slice": [ 
      {
        "origin": "ZZZ",
        "destination": "ZZZ",
        "date": "YYYY-MM-DD"
      }
    ],
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1
    },
    "solutions": 20
  }
}
```

1. At least one slice, but needs to be an array
2. Origin, destination and future date needed
3. Passengers is also required.

Assuming that you get the service like this:

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();

    $client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);

    $this->client = $client;
    $this->service = new \Google_Service_QPXExpress($this->client);
```

The search request could be like this:

```
    $slices = [];

    $slice = new \Google_Service_QPXExpress_SliceInput();

    $slice->setOrigin($origin);
    $slice->setDestination($destination);
    $slice->setDate(isset($date)? $date->format('Y-m-d') : '2015-08-13' );

    $slices[] = $slice;

    $passengers = new \Google_Service_QPXExpress_PassengerCounts();
    $passengers->setAdultCount($pax);

    $options = new \Google_Service_QPXExpress_TripOptionsRequest();
    $options->setSlice($slices);
    $options->setPassengers($passengers);
    $options->setSolutions(20);

    $request = new \Google_Service_QPXExpress_TripsSearchRequest();
    $request->setRequest($options);

    /** @var \Google_Service_QPXExpress_TripsSearchResponse $result */
    $result = $this->service->trips->search($request);

    /** @var \Google_Service_QPXExpress_TripOptionsResponse $trips */
    $trips = $result->getTrips();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, as if you need to continue like so:

```
$result = $service->$trips->search(new Google_Service_QPXExpress_TripsSearchRequest());
$trips = $result->getTrips();
$data =  $trips->getData(); //Google_Service_QPXExpress_Data
$aircraft = $data->getAircraft();
```

hope this gets you further. cheers!

(you might have to parametrise the search)